# java jsp returns object's address

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have the next situation.
To JSP I forward List of objects Category and iterate over it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:forEach var="category" items="${categories}">
            <a href="/mytest/projects?category=${category}"><c:out value="${category.id} - ${category.name}"/></a><p>
        </c:forEach>
    </body>

</html>
```

As a result list of links to specific projects is shown. Now the problem is that JSP returns address of object **${category}** as String like:

```
projects?category=data.Category@6892b54
```

How can I reach this object via its address back in servlet? I could return back its *id* and initiate simply by **new Category(*id*)** but I strongly feel that there is a way to access object already existing.

In servlet I try to get to object using what I know:

```
Category category = req.getParameter("category");
```

But compiler returns error that String can not be casted to Category(((

Comment: There's a few critical misunderstandings here. HTML is text, and it is rendered on the client. Servlet are on the server. This notation `data.Category@6892b54` is the default `toString` output. Override the `toString` method in the corresponding class and you'll get different output. `${xyz}` calls `toString` on the attribute named `xyz`.

Answer (score 2):

`${category}` is doing a reference to the attribute with name `category`. This attribute may be in request, session or application scope. If you have this directly in your jsp:

```
${category}
```

It will call `toString` method of the object found there. Since you haven't overridden that method, it uses `Object#toString`.

To avoid all this, you should pass some identifier of the entity as parameter in the query string. From your code, this should do:

```
<a href="/mytest/projects?category=${category.id}">
```

And in the controller you're pre processing the GET request, read the parameter `"category"` and do the proper data lookup.

Comment: But it gives me only id of Category. Now to create an object - I can do only new Category(and create some kind of twin of existing Category object).

Comment: That's what you have to do: read the id, use the id to lookup in your data source for the proper data and create a new instance of `Category`. That's how this works. It's not like you can pass the category object through the net unless you serialize it, but that compromises data.

Comment: So it means that I can not play with object addresses? Return address from client instead of id and just access existing object by its address. To not show address in browser I could use POST instead of GET

Comment: No, you can't. In Java, there's no way you can access to an *address* of memory in a clean way. And the ways to do it may compromise the whole application since you will be playing with the JVM.